# When (in-place) upgrading to 11.04 are existing installs transferred to Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, upgrade, default

Just wondering what the **default** is/will be for 10.10 users currently using the standard gnome-panel desktop, who decided to upgrade through Update Manager.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default will be upgraded with your gold rules: we don't touch user tweaks, but just upgrade the defaults we already provided.

That means that if you are using the ubuntu 10.10 default (the gnome-panel session), you will be transitioned to ubuntu 11.04 default (the Unity session) on upgrade. However, if you changed your session configuration to something else in 10.10 (like starting KDE/Openbox), we don't touch that and you will be still have your user defined session after the upgrade.